# BackAndroid is deprecated and has been removed from this package. Use BackHandler instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, node-modules, npm-install

I updated the version of React, Expo and React-Native

Now I have a red screen on my device saying that BackAndroid is deprecated and has been removed from this package. Use BackHandler instead But I don't where is BackAndroid, I can't know it is used in which package.
That's my package.json

```
"@expo/vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.3",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source": "^6.22.0",
        "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
        "expo": "^33.0.0",
        "lato-font": "^3.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.14",
        "react": "16.8.3",
        "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
        "react-native-app-intro-slider": "0.2.4",
        "react-native-bottomsheet": "^1.9.3",
        "react-native-customisable-switch": "^0.1.0",
        "react-native-dialog-input": "^1.0.7",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.0-alpha.43",
        "react-native-image-base64": "^0.1.3",
        "react-native-js-bottom-sheet": "^1.1.0",
        "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
        "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.0.1",
        "react-native-modal": "5.4.0",
        "react-native-modalbox": "^1.7.1",
        "react-native-prompt": "^1.0.0",
        "react-native-prompt-android": "^0.3.5",
        "react-native-swipeable": "^0.6.0",
        "react-native-tab-view": "^0.0.77",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.2.0",
        "react-navigation": "^2.18.0",
        "react-waterfall": "3.0.7",
        "sentry-expo": "^1.7.0",
        "tcomb-form-native": "0.6.11",
        "timeago.js": "^3.0.2"
```

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9plpm.png)

Comment: It is necessary to find out the difference between when an error occurs and when an error does not occur.